# update value of main window from a popup window

Tags: java, javascript, html, spring, jsp

I'm trying to update the shopping cart quantity of the main window from a popup window.

How can I call the shopping cart controller from the popup before closing it and then display the result in main window?

I'm trying to call the spring controller using javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.opener` is a reference back to the opening window. Here's some sample code:

win1.html:

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('win2.html');">pop up</a><br/>
<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = myvar;">set var</a>
<div id="mydiv"></div>
```

win2.html:

```
<script>
window.opener.document.getElementById("mydiv").innerHTML = "test";
window.opener.myvar = "test2";
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks... I've used 'window.opener.location.reload();' for my purpose. It refreshed the parent window and cart qty updated..

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but more of a pointer. Oliver has given the right answer. If you are willing to experiment with new ways for achieving this you can try cross window messaging available in newer browsers. Here's a link to get you started

http://ejohn.org/blog/cross-window-messaging/